# MySQL select from multiple tables, but always get data from one

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new to SQL stuff and I'm trying to make a login form in php. I want the login form to do a bit of ip blocking to prevent brute force attacks. So, I have two tables - users and loginattempts. I'm trying to do a select that will return the user's name/id if the username/password combination is correct, but regardless of its correctness I want the result of the login attempt query. Here's a bit of code.

First, I make sure there is an entry in the loginattempt table by doing:

```
INSERT INTO loginattempts (ip) VALUES(:ip)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attempt=attempt+1
```

Then, I want to do a select similar to:

```
SELECT users.username, users.id, loginattempts.attempt
             FROM users, loginattempts
             WHERE users.username = :username
             AND users.password = :password
             AND loginattempts.ip = :ip
```

However, this obviously won't work if any of the conditions aren't met. How could I achieve this in a single query?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two tables?

Comment: Nah, they're completely separate. The only real relationship is that they're accessed at the same time, which is why I want to do it in a single query.

Comment: It might be better to record in `loginattempts` the *time* of the the last *failed* login from each connecting IP and deny further login attempts from such IPs for a fixed period of time after their failed attempt.  It's not unusual to make such time period a function of the number of consecutive failed attempts, such that one is blocked for increasingly longer periods: maybe 1 second initially, then 5 seconds, then 20 seconds, then 1 minute, then 5 minutes, etc: causes minimum disruption to genuine users getting their credentials wrong, whilst frustrating brute force attacks.

Comment: What would be the best way to store the time? I was looking into DATETIME, but I'm not too sure how to manipulate the data from php. Would I do the time increments from within the mysql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the tables are not related, this is probably most easily accomplished with a subselect to get the login attempts:

```
SELECT
  users.username,
  users.id,
  /* COALESCE() to return 0 if no attempt yet logged */
  COALESCE((SELECT attempt FROM loginattempts WHERE ip = :ip),0) AS attempt
FROM uusers
WHERE 
  username = :username
  AND password = :password
```

It is possible to do a tricky cartesian join to pull the attempt, but since you are looking for a discrete row for both the user and ip, this will probably be fast enough. Just make sure you have an index on `loginattempts.ip`.

#### Update

If you *must* get a row back under any circumstance, you can the tricky left join I mentioned above. Since only one row will be returned by the ip, you can get away with a cartesian join (no `ON` clause):

```
SELECT
  username,
  userid,
  attempt
FROM
  /* Should always return exactly one row */
  (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT attempt FROM loginattempts WHERE ip = :ip),0) AS attempt)
  /* left joins against users with no ON condition, so if user doesn't match NULLs will return */
  LEFT JOIN users
WHERE 
  username = :username
  AND password = :password
```

Comment: Thanks, but that query doesn't seem to be returning any data (ie attempt) if the username/password is incorrect though.

Comment: @user1520427 What would you expect it to return? Usually for login checks, you depend on no row returned if the user/pass is invalid. You just check in your code if a row is present - if not, it's an invalid login attempt.  You don't need the ip attempt at that point either, since have already logged and incremented this attempt.

Comment: I was hoping to get the attempt so that I could set the block time appropriately, as suggested by eggyal. How would you go about doing such a thing?